openpyxl не закрывает файл
Простой код для примера:
import openpyxl
path = *путь к файлу*
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
wb.close()

Если после этого открываю файл в экселе, то эксель не дает сохранить никакие изменения в файле из-за конфликта доступа.
Код запускаю в idle. Возможность редактировать файл в экселе возвращается, только если закрыть idle.
Есть ли возможность с этим как-то бороться?
Если у кого-то та же проблема, по итогу помог вариант, предложенный CrazyElf:
import openpyxl
import gc
path = *путь к файлу*
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
gc.collect()
wb.close()


А если del wb ещё в конце сделать? И может import gc; gc.collect()? А файл вы только читаете или ещё и пишете? Если только читаете, попробуйте открывать с ключом readonly.

Вариант с del wb попробовал, не помогло. Файл читаю и пишу.

И gc.collect() после этого если, не помогает? Ну, какой-то глюк прям, не знаю. А idle не может за какими-то переменными следить и из-за этого объекты не освобождать? Тогда это никак не вылечится.

gc.collect() помогло. Спасибо!

Добавлю тогда в виде ответа )

Хм, даже до wb.close() gc.collect() помогает? Это странно )

Вам может помочь удаление переменной wb из памяти и принудительная сборка мусора после этого:
import gc

...
wb.close()
del wb
gc.collect()


Вероятнее всего это происходит потому что, openpyxl открывает несколько файловых дескрипторов, но при этом built-in функция _get_source() возвращает лишь один для закрытия.
Загружайте файл через память и используйте режим read_only.
import openpyxl
path = *путь к файлу*
memoryCopy = None
with open(path, "rb") as f:
    memoryCopy = io.BytesIO(f.read())

wb = load_workbook(memoryCopy, read_only=True)


Мне нужно дописать данные в файл, read_only к сожалению не подходит
